# How to automatically wake up cmd the system in hibernate mode without using Task scheduler?

Tags: windows, command-line, hibernate

I need a script for setting system to go to the hibernate mode for 20 secs and after 20 secs automatically it has to wake up.

```
timeout /t 20 /NOBREAK > NUL && shutdown /h
```

I am able to send to hibernate mode for 20 secs but didn’t wake up after 20 secs.

What is the correct command?

Comment: I'm not sure code can execute if the computer is in this low power state. What version of Windows are you using? Also what is your use case for this command?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernated computer is completely turned off. You can even safely unplug it from power.

Computers don't execute code when they're turned off, so what you want to achieve is not possible.

Some BIOSes can be configured to power on at certain time, but there's no way to wait for some amount of time, then power on. There's just no practical use case for such feature. We may be able to suggest some solution if you could tell us what's the point of this unusual operation.

Comment: we can able to do these kind of  power cycle  that's what i looking for it  , i just want automatically wake up command hibernate

Comment: or if you know any program in python script for setting time for hibernate and wake up. post the script here anything it's fine

Comment: I have explained that it's **impossible**. A hibernated computer is **turned off**, it **doesn't run any scripts**. What are you trying to achieve by hibernating a computer and booting it 20 seconds later? What's your goal?

Comment: i can't tell what i trying ? what i need system has to be hibernate in 20s and it has to wake up another 20s that's all. like you said maybe it's not possible  if it is possible let me know

Comment: Please read [What is the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029). This power cycle is your proposed solution to some problem. It's such a weird idea that I'm almost sure there's a better way. But I'm not able to help you because I don't know what's the actual problem you're trying to solve. If you want useful answers, you have to ask the actual issue you're solving. Your proposed solution is impossible to implement.

Comment: @gronostaj - According to [this document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-states), it's possible to resume from hibernation (S4 power state) (albeit from an external trigger it seems)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Yes, that would work. But it can't be scripted. OP seems to be assuming that a hibernated PC is still executing code. That's a contradiction.

Comment: @gronostaj - indeed, the external trigger is key. Perhaps OP is not aware there are more low power states. We keep talking about hibernate but perhaps for his use case, another state is sufficient. That's for OP to clear up.